# Address Sanitizer Xcode -7.2.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

I have my AddressSanitizer checkbox ticked from the edit scheme of Xcode.Now when I run my code I come across the following log:
**"AddressSanitizer debugger support is active. Memory error breakpoint has been installed and you can now use the 'memory history' command."**
Any ideas what Xcode is trying to tell me.

Comment: Why don't you uncheck it and forget about it if you don't understand it?

Comment: Well as I have heard in WWDC - AddressSanitizer helps a great deal to debug crashes. I would very much like to know if this log points to a feature that I can use.

Comment: OK so you are interested in learning how to use the address sanitizer?

Comment: I am particularly interested - 'memory history' command and how to use it.